# Error connecting to mysql using XPages rest service

Tags: mysql, rest, xpages

Getting a error 500 "internal Error" when attempting to connect to a mysql database via xpages rest service.  Mysql ver 8, Domino Server 9.0.1 FP8.
Using JDBC jar file from the mysql.
Can anyone help me with troubleshooting error.

Error:

```
code    500
text    "Internal Error"
message "Error while reading the relational data"
type    "text"
data    "com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Error while reading the relational data
        at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.jdbc.services.content.JsonJdbcQueryContent.writeJdbcQuery(JsonJdbcQueryContent.java:269)
        at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.jdbc.rest.query.RestJdbcQueryJsonService.renderServiceJSONGet(RestJdbcQueryJsonService.java:228)
        at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.jdbc.rest.query.RestJdbcQueryJsonService.renderService(RestJdbcQueryJsonService.java:66)
        at com.ibm.domino.services.HttpServiceEngine.processRequest(HttpServiceEngine.java:168)
        at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rest.UIBaseRestService._processAjaxRequest(UIBaseRestService.java:257)
        at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rest.UIBaseRestService.processAjaxRequest(UIBaseRestService.java:234)
        at com.ibm.xsp.util.AjaxUtilEx.renderAjaxPartialLifecycle(AjaxUtilEx.java:206)
        at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.renderAjaxPartial(FacesServletEx.java:249)
        at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceAjaxPartialView(FacesServletEx.java:200)
        at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceAjaxPartialViewSync(FacesServletEx.java:169)
        at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:155)
        at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:159)
        at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
        at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
        at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:588)
        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
        at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:865)
        at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:808)
        at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:577)
        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
        at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
        at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException
        at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.util.JdbcUtil.createNamedConnection(JdbcUtil.java:87)
        at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.jdbc.services.content.JsonJdbcQueryContent.findConnection(JsonJdbcQueryContent.java:103)
        at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.jdbc.services.content.JsonJdbcQueryContent.writeJdbcQuery(JsonJdbcQueryContent.java:139)
        ... 24 more
    Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: comp/env/jdbc/mysqlActor
        at com.ibm.pvc.jndi.internal.provider.java.FlatMappingContext.lookup(FlatMappingContext.java:118)
        at com.ibm.pvc.jndi.internal.provider.java.FlatMappingContext.lookup(FlatMappingContext.java:140)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:428)
        at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.util.JdbcUtil.createNamedConnection(JdbcUtil.java:81)
        ... 26 more"
```

xpage xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:label
        value="MySQLConnectionTest"
        id="label1">
    </xp:label>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xe:restService
        id="restService1"
        pathInfo="actorData">
        <xe:this.service>
            <xe:jdbcQueryJsonService
                contentType="application/json"
                sqlTable="sakila.actor"
                connectionName="mysqlActor">
            </xe:jdbcQueryJsonService>
        </xe:this.service>
    </xe:restService>

</xp:view>

<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jdbc type="dbcp">
    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.driver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:mysql://9900w7.int.natc-ht.com:3306;databaseName=sakila</url>
    <user>root</user>
    <password>password</password>
    <dbcp>
        <maxTotal>5</maxTotal>
        <maxIdle>5</maxIdle>
    </dbcp>
</jdbc>
```

Comment: The error says: "javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: comp/env/jdbc/mysqlActor". Is your jdbc config stored in a file called mysqlActor.jdbc in WebContent/WEB-INF/jdbc/? Have you read chapter 12 in the XPages Extension Library book and installed the JDBC driver correctly?

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I corrected the connection name.  it should be mysql which is the name of the file "mysql.jdbc" in the jdbc folder.  I'm getting a error.

Comment: And did it help? :-)

Comment: I've been following paper from connect2016 by Paul Calhoun and chapter 12,  The mysql driver is in a update site. I'm getting a error.  I'm getting the error Cannot find class com.mysql.jdbc.driver in NSF.  The driver is in  the update site on that server and server have been restarted.  I'm missing something with how the driver is used from a update site ?

Comment: Made sure the mysql driver show on the server osgi.  mysql.jdbc currently is:<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jdbc type="simple">
The driver
 <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.driver</driver>
 <url>jdbc:mysql://9900w7.int.natc-ht.com:3306/sakila</url>
 <user>root</user>
 <password>usencg22</password>
</jdbc>
<simple>
 <minPoolSize>10</minPoolSize>
 <maxPoolSize>20</maxPoolSize>
 <maxConectionSize>200</maxConnectionSize>
</simple>
Drive seem to load but get an error: com.ibm.commons.xml.XMLException: Error parsing XML stream

Comment: Try removing the <?xml part from your jdbc file so that it begins with <jdbc and ends with <(jdbc>. The example file in the XPages Extension Library book on page 409 does not contain the <?xml line

Comment: Tried removing <?xml part didn't make a different.
Error from the response are:
com.ibm.designer.runtime.resources.ResourceFactoriesException: Error while loading connection mysqlData\r\n\tat
com.ibm.commons.xml.XMLException: Error parsing XML stream\r\n\tat com.ibm.commons.xml.drivers.XercesDriver.parse(XercesDriver.java:65)\r\n\tat
The osgi at the service state the driver is resolved
tell http osgi ss mysql
Framework is launched.
id State       Bundle
11 RESOLVED    com.mysql.jdbc.driver_1.0.0.20190318-0754

Comment: Trying to see if I can do java class to test the mysql connection.  And I confirm the mysql server can be access remotely from another computer.

Comment: Create java class to test the driver and connection.  Was able to read data from the mysql db.  Had to add these lines to the java policy:
grant {
   permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getClassLoader";
   permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "setContextClassLoader";
   permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";
   permission java.io.FilePermission "${java.home}/lib/-", "read";  
};

The driver com.mysql.jdbc.driver has been depreciated the new com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Rest service is still not working.  Same error as above with Parsing XML Stream

Comment: This may have some to do with code 500. Error while reading the relational data. On the server console I'm getting this error: HTTP JVM: [Fatal Error] :7:2: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

Comment: Yes this and the other error about XML could indicate an issue with some XML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a combination of jdbc config file and driver location. For mysql the config needs to config like the example below.  Thank you Henrik for putting on the write track.

```
<jdbc type="simple">
    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:mysql://9900w7.int.natc-ht.com</url>
    <port>3306</port>
    <databaseName>weather</databaseName>
    <user>root</user>
    <password>password</password>
    <simple>
        <minPoolSize>10</minPoolSize>
        <maxPoolSize>20</maxPoolSize>
    </simple>
</jdbc>
```